# How to increase FaceNet accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorboard

I'm currently working on my thesis where I'm going to compare the facial recognition techniques Eigenface, Fisherface and CNN in regards to accuracy and speed. I'm currently trying to train my own model for the CNN using [FaceNet](https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet).

The problem I have is that I cannot seem to get the models accuracy above 71% and the maximum I've managed for the classifier is 80%. I'm using a small subset of the LFW dataset that contains 10 classes with 40 images each for training and 4 images each for testing.

I tried the following parameters which gave an accuracy of 77.5% using the classifier and ~71% on the models forward passes:

```
/*
 * Alignment
 */
python3 src/align/align_dataset_mtcnn.py ~/datasets/custom2/raw/training/ ~/datasets/custom2/aligned_182/training --image_size 182 --margin 44

python3 src/align/align_dataset_mtcnn.py ~/datasets/custom2/raw/testing/ ~/datasets/custom2/aligned_182/testing --image_size 182 --margin 44

/*
 * Training
 */
python3 src/train_softmax.py \
--logs_base_dir ~/logs/facenet/ \
--models_base_dir ~/models/facenet/ \
--data_dir ~/datasets/custom2/aligned_182/training/ \
--image_size 160 \
--model_def models.inception_resnet_v1 \
--lfw_dir ~/datasets/lfw/lfw_aligned_160/ \
--optimizer ADAM \
--learning_rate -1 \
--max_nrof_epochs 150 \
--keep_probability 0.8 \
--random_crop \
--random_flip \
--use_fixed_image_standardization \
--learning_rate_schedule_file data/learning_rate_schedule_classifier_casia.txt \
--weight_decay 5e-4 \
--embedding_size 512 \
--lfw_distance_metric 1 \
--lfw_use_flipped_images \
--lfw_subtract_mean \
--validation_set_split_ratio 0.05 \
--validate_every_n_epochs 5 \
--prelogits_norm_loss_factor 5e-4

python3 src/freeze_graph.py ~/models/facenet/20190402-225816/ ~/models/facenet/20190402-225816/model.pb

python3 src/classifier.py TRAIN ~/datasets/custom2/aligned_182/training/ ~/models/facenet/20190402-225816/model.pb ~/models/facenet/20190402-225816/classifier.pkl --batch_size 1000

/*
 * Test verification
 */
python3 src/classifier.py CLASSIFY ~/datasets/custom2/aligned_182/testing/ ~/models/facenet/20190402-225816/model.pb ~/models/facenet/20190402-225816/classifier.pkl --batch_size 1000
```

But before that I tried the following ones that gave an accuracy of 80% with the classifier and ~68% on the forward passes:

```
/*
 * Alignment
 */
for N in {1..4}; do python3 src/align/align_dataset_mtcnn.py ~/datasets/custom2/raw/training ~/datasets/custom2/aligned_160/training --image_size 160 --margin 32 --random_order --gpu_memory_fraction 0.2 & done

/*
 * Training
 */
python3 src/train_softmax.py \
--logs_base_dir ~/logs/facenet/ \
--models_base_dir ~/models/facenet/ \
--data_dir ~/datasets/custom2/aligned_160/training \
--image_size 160 \
--model_def models.inception_resnet_v1 \
--lfw_dir ~/datasets/lfw/lfw_aligned_160 \
--optimizer RMSPROP \
--learning_rate 0.01 \
--weight_decay 1e-4 \
--max_nrof_epochs 100 \
--gpu_memory_fraction 0.95

python3 src/freeze_graph.py ~/models/facenet/20190401-114728/ ~/models/facenet/20190401-114728/model.pb

python3 src/classifier.py TRAIN ~/datasets/custom2/aligned_160/training/ ~/models/facenet/20190401-114728/model.pb ~/models/facenet/20190401-114728/classifier.pkl --batch_size 1000

/*
 * Verification
 */
python3 src/classifier.py CLASSIFY ~/datasets/custom2/aligned_160/testing/ ~/models/facenet/20190401-114728/model.pb ~/models/facenet/20190401-114728/classifier.pkl --batch_size 1000
```

The accuracy of the model itself on the LFW forward passes are better in the first one at ~71% instead of ~68% accuracy but with the classifier it's 77.5% instead of 80%. My question is what I should do to achieve a higher accuracy.
I'd like to get over 90% if possible. I can see on the graphs I gathered from tensorboard that the model is all over the place during training. These graphs are from the model with ~71% accuracy:

[image: LFW Accuracy]
[image: Total Loss]
[image: Cross Entropy 1]

And these are from the first model with ~68% accuracy:

[image: LFW Accuracy]
[image: Total Loss]
[image: Cross Entropy 1]

I would like to achieve an accuracy of 90+% using my own model if possible since I'm going to compare it to other techniques.

If any more information is needed in order to help me just let me know! Does anyone here know what I should try in order to achieve an accuracy of 90+%?

Thanks in advance!